# Create web config file in angular 5 project?

Tags: angular

I have created an angular 5 web site, with Webform or MVC I want to deploy to customers, I just want to change some variables (dbconnection, name, ...) in the webconfig file, but with angular I don't know how to do it. So every time I deploy, I have to build again, so is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5):

try to add this as `web.config` file with `dist` folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="./index.html" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

for more i recommend reading this article: https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/deploy-an-angular-application-to-iis-60a0897742e7

Comment: If you do this but get an error about a malformed xml document, you need the "IIS rewrite" module added to IIS: https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite . Otherwise it cannot understand what <rewrite> means.

Answer (score -1):

You should use the environment.ts and add whatever your endpoints there.

Something like this,

**environment.ts file:**

```
export const environment = {
    production: false,
    apiBase: 'http://dev-server:4200/app/',
    env: 'dev'
};
```

Here is a really **[`good article`](http://tattoocoder.com/angular-cli-using-the-environment-option/)** on environment files with angular cli: